# Set a User-Agent for SSH

Tags: ssh, user-agent

How can I set a user agent for the ssh program? Network requests made without a user agent are blocked on my network and I'm wondering if ssh is throwing a "Connection reset by peer" error because of this. I know it's not related to ports because I've tried many different common and uncommon ports to no avail.

Does the ssh program send one by default?

Comment: Are you sure this is the issue? What's the actual error message shown?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*User agent* is a HTTP header, and SSH doesn't use the HTTP protocol. Therefore, SSH cannot specify a user agent.

It's more likely that destination port 22 is blocked. To circumvent this, you can specify additional listening ports on the server in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Example:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
Port 8080
```

In your client machine, you have to specify the port either manually when connecting or in the config file.

Example for manual method:

```
ssh -p 8080 example.com
```

Example entry in system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or the per-user `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host example.com
Port 8080
```

If your conections get blocked due to packet inspection, you may need to use a HTTPS proxy. Apache2 can be used as a proxy if it's already installed.

If you install a HTTPS proxy on your server, you can use this command

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x example.com:8080 %h %p" example.com
```

or add

```
Host example.com
Port ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x example.com:8080 %h %p
```

in a SSH config file.

You could also use a web-based solution like [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. It's not the ports though, I've tried 80, 8080, 1337, etc.

Comment: Packet inspection can distinguish real HTTP traffic from other traffic on port 80. Some workplaces/ISPs also force you to send all outgoing traffic through their proxy. DO you use a proxy in your web beowser?

Comment: No, but you might be correct on the packet inspection. Is there any alternative to ssh that uses https or something? Not a glype proxy or anything, but a secure terminal access.

Comment: You can keep using SSH with a proxy. Does the server have apache2 installed?

Comment: I can install it. I guess I should look up a guide for http proxies through Apache then? Or maybe a VPN...

Comment: VPN would be great if allowed. But if SSH access is blocked... apache2 can be used as a proxy, but that only makes sense if it's already installed. If you install a HTTPS proxy on your server, you can use `ssh -o "ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x example.com:8080 %h %p" example.com`. You could also use a web-based solution like [shellinabox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/).